# How to execute a code on focus of textarea just once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a teatarea like this:

```js
$("textarea").on('focus', function(){
  alert("clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea col="3" row="20"></textarea>
```

As you see in the above fiddle, every time when you focus on that textarea, `alert()` executes. How can I limit it to executes just one time? *(just first time)*

Comment: You can set variable first_time=true and check for that variable in focus

Comment: @JasminMistry Yeah I knew that approach already .. But personally I hate using variable for this kind of usages ..!

Comment: Yeah you are correct. adeneo's ans is perfect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
$("textarea").one('focus', function(){
  alert("clicked");
});
```

> The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for it ... +1

Comment: Can I ask another short question?

Comment: I have two events, and I want to mix them by `or`. this: `$(document).on('click', '.textarea_tools > i', function(e) {` and this `$("#qandatextarea").on('focus', function(e){`, Is that possible?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking, but maybe something like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/xrw45fxw/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a counter system that way if your change your mind on how many times you want to trigger the alert on focus you can just change the if then statement value.

```
//initalize the counter
var count = 0;

//set the limit
var limit = 0;

//on focus event
$("textarea").on('focus', function(){

   //if the count equals the limit
   if(count === limit){

     //alert the message
     alert("clicked");

   }

//increment the count
count++;

});
```

Comment: Thank you, it will work .. But as I mentioned in the comments I hate this way `:-)` ... +1 for your solution

Comment: Not a problem, I apologize I didn't see your comment until I posted my answer.